# SQL subquery incorrect syntax converting column to NewID() value

Tags: sql-server-2008, select

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Ids
( 
   DlId nvarchar(32) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   DlIdGUID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO dbo.Ids
(DlId, REPLACE(DlId, DlId, newid()))
(SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 DriversLic FROM Student.dbo.StudDL
WHERE DlId LIKE '%345%')
```

The error says

> Incorrect syntax near '('

Comment: Your intent is not clear, do you want new guids for the 5 rows?

Comment: Yes, I want to insert the 5 IDs and their GUID into the table Ids

Comment: Well, you need to remove the `(` before `SELECT` and the last `)`. Also it's not clear what your `REPLACE()` function is really supposed to be doing. If you just want the whole value to be a new GUID, why bother mentioning the existing column there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert the matching `DriversLic` and new GUIDs;

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Ids (DlId, DlIdGUID)
    (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 DriversLic, NEWID() 
     FROM Student.dbo.StudDL 
     WHERE DlId LIKE '%345%')
```

With `DISTINCT`:

```
;with T(DriversLic) as (
    select distinct top 5 DriversLic from StudDL 
)
insert Ids  
    select DriversLic, NEWID() from T
```

Comment: I am receiving another error  that I'm getting a violation of the primary key constraint on DlId ..???

Comment: I am using the DISTINCT modifier in my sub select

Comment: Then there is probably a DlId in Ids with the same value as one you are trying to insert as a new row

Comment: The table is currently empty

Comment: that is, the Ids table is empty

Comment: The NEWID() in the select is making every row DISTINCT, you can pre select the IDs only

Comment: I don't understand the syntax but it does work ...thank you very much.